networking disabled after upgrading ubuntu to 24.04
I cannot establish any network connection after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04. The upgrade prompted me to reinstall nvidia 550 drivers in ubuntu recovery mode (driver issues). In the recovery mode I could enable a network connection with USB tethering using my Android phone. After reinstalling drivers successfully and rebooting ubuntu I could not establish any network connection either by usb tethering, cabled connection, or usb wifi adapter. Also the onboard network adapter for the cabled connection is listed as UNCLAIMED. I have no idea how to approach this. Any input appreciated
